# csv import using phpMyAdmin - handling extraneous comma

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So my table has 5 columns and my CSV file has 5 fields but it has a comma at the end as follows:

```
123, abc, xyz, 321, 456,
```

and this is causing issues. I keep getting `Invalid column count in CSV input on line`

On the import page, there's a field `Lines terminated with:` where I tried using `\r\n,` which works when I perform `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` (using `LINES TERMINATED BY ',\r\n'`), but this results in `Invalid parameter for CSV import: Lines terminated with`

Is there a way to handle an extraneous comma at the end of a CSV row?

Comment: Are you using Linux, Windows, or a Mac as the computer you're trying to upload from?

Comment: This is a Windows computer

Comment: I posted a solution that includes a PowerShell script you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are just text files with some structure. That means that basic find and replace will work. Assuming this isn't a huge file, you could open it with VIM/Notepad++/Sublime Text and do a find and replace.

Essentially replace `,\n` (or `,\r\n` depending on what it has) with `\n`. If the file is too large to open in a standard editor, you'll probably need to use a command line interface.

On Linux and Mac computers you can use `sed` to do this.

```bash
sed -i 's/,\n/\n/g' file.txt
```

On a Windows computer you can use PowerShell to do the same thing.

```powershell
(Get-Content file.txt -Raw).replace(",`r`n", [System.Environment]::NewLine) | Set-Content file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a spare column using ALTER TABLE just for the import, make it allow nulls. Then use ALTER TABLE after import to remove the additional temporary column.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)